# How do I beat the Swim Trunks?

Tags: pushmo

I am stuck on the Pushmo level Swim Trunks, in the Murals section.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get to the top of the trunks to save the Pushmo kid.

Help! I feel bad for the kid trapped in the swim trunks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pull the bottom right piece and the large dark-blue piece left of it as far as you can.
2. Pull the right mirrored-L piece once or twice, jump on it and jump to the large piece you've pulled out
3. Pull the large piece twice
4. Jump to the gap on the right, pull the mirrored-L piece once
5. Climb to the top right corner, pull the blue piece once

Comment: You are a serious lifesaver when it comes to playing this game!

Comment: Yes, lucky for me until now you needed help in the early levels, by the late levels where solution can take up to 20+ minutes, I don't think I'll be able to write a step by step explanation, maybe I can do video guides :)